# Need help understanding Iterator lifetimes

Tags: rust

Consider the following code:

```
#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct Stride<'a, I: Index<uint> + 'a> {
    items: I,
    len: uint,
    current_idx: uint,
    stride: uint,
}

impl<'a, I> Iterator for Stride<'a, I> where I: Index<uint> {
    type Item = &'a <I as Index<uint>>::Output;

    #[inline]
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<&'a <I as Index<uint>>::Output> {
        if (self.current_idx >= self.len) {
            None
        } else {
            let idx = self.current_idx;
            self.current_idx += self.stride;
            Some(self.items.index(&idx))
        }
    }
}
```

This currently errors, saying that the compiler cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for the `Some(self.items.index(&idx))` line. What should the lifetime of the return value be? I believe it should be the same lifetime as `self.items`, because the `Index` trait method returns a reference with the same lifetime as the `Index` implementor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [definition](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/ea6f65c5f1a3f84e010d2cef02a0160804e9567a/src/libcore/ops.rs#L805-L810) of `Index` is:

```
pub trait Index<Index: ?Sized> {
    type Output: ?Sized;
    /// The method for the indexing (`Foo[Bar]`) operation
    fn index<'a>(&'a self, index: &Index) -> &'a Self::Output;
}
```

Specifically, `index` returns a reference to an element where the reference has the same lifetime as `self`. That is, it borrows `self`.

In your case, the `self` of the `index` call (which could be `&self.items[idx]` btw) is `self.items`, so the compiler sees that the return value has to be restricted to be borrowed from `self.items`, but `items` is owned by `next`'s `self`, so a borrow from `self.items` is a borrow from `self` itself.

That is to say, the compiler can only guarantee the return value of `index` is valid for as long as `self` lives (and various concerns about mutation), so the lifetimes of `&mut self` and the returned `&...` have to be linked.

If one compiles it, to see the error, linking the references is what the compiler suggests:

```
<anon>:23:29: 23:40 error: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for autoref due to conflicting requirements
<anon>:23             Some(self.items.index(&idx))
                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~
<anon>:17:5: 25:6 help: consider using an explicit lifetime parameter as shown: fn next(&'a mut self) -> Option<&'a <I as Index<uint>>::Output>
<anon>:17     fn next(&mut self) -> Option<&'a <I as Index<uint>>::Output> {
<anon>:18         if (self.current_idx >= self.len) {
<anon>:19             None
<anon>:20         } else {
<anon>:21             let idx = self.current_idx;
<anon>:22             self.current_idx += self.stride;
          ...
```

However, the suggested signature `fn next(&'a mut self) -> Option<&'a <I as Index<uint>>::Output>` is more restrictive than signature of the `Iterator` trait, and so is illegal. (Iterators with this arrangement of lifetimes may be useful, but they do not work with many common consumers, like `.collect`.)

The problem the compiler is protecting against is demonstrated by a type like:

```
struct IndexablePair<T>  {
    x: T, y: T
}

impl Index<uint> for IndexablePair<T> {
    type Output = T;
    fn index(&self, index: &uint) -> &T {
        match *index {
            0 => &self.x,
            1 => &self.y,
            _ => panic!("out of bounds")
        }
    }
}
```

This stores two `T`s inline (e.g. straight on the stack) and allows for indexing them `pair[0]` and `pair[1]`. The `index` method returns a pointer straight into that memory (e.g. the stack), so if an `IndexablePair` value moves in memory, those pointers will become invalid, e.g. (assume `Stride::new(items: I, len: uint, stride: uint)`):

```
let pair = IndexablePair { x: "foo".to_string(), y: "bar".to_string() };

let mut stride = Stride::new(pair, 2, 1);

let value = stride.next();

// allocate some memory and move stride into, changing its address
let mut moved = box stride;

println!("value is {}", value);
```

That penultimate line is bad! It invalidates `value` because the `stride`, and it's field `items` (the pair) is moved in memory so the reference inside `value` is then pointing to moved data; which is highly unsafe and very bad.

The suggested lifetimes stop this problem (and several other problematic ones) by borrowing `stride` and disallowing the move, but, as we saw above we can't use that.

A technique to resole this is to separate the memory storing the elements from the iterator itself, that is, change the definition of `Stride` to:

```
pub struct Stride<'a, I: Index<uint> + 'a> {
    items: &'a I,
    len: uint,
    current_idx: uint,
    stride: uint,
}
```

(Adding a reference to `items`.)

The compiler then has the guarantee that the memory storing the elements is independent of the `Stride` value (that is, moving `Stride` around in memory won't invalidate the old elements) because there's a non-owning pointer separating them. This version compiles fine:

```
use std::ops::Index;

#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct Stride<'a, I: Index<uint> + 'a> {
    items: &'a I,
    len: uint,
    current_idx: uint,
    stride: uint,
}

impl<'a, I> Iterator for Stride<'a, I> where I: Index<uint> {
    type Item = &'a <I as Index<uint>>::Output;

    #[inline]
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<&'a <I as Index<uint>>::Output> {
        if (self.current_idx >= self.len) {
            None
        } else {
            let idx = self.current_idx;
            self.current_idx += self.stride;
            Some(self.items.index(&idx))
        }
    }
}
```

(Theoretically one could add a `?Sized` bound in there, probably by manually implementing `Clone` instead of `derive`ing it, so that `Stride` can be used directly with a `&[T]`, i.e. `Stride::new(items: &I, ...)` `Stride::new(&[1, 2, 3], ...)` would work, rather than having to have a double layer of `Stride::new(&&[1, 2, 3], ...)` as the default `Sized` bound requires.)

[playpen](http://play.rust-lang.org/?code=%23!%5Bfeature%28associated_types%29%5D%0A%0Ause%20std%3A%3Aops%3A%3AIndex%3B%0A%0A%23%5Bderive%28Clone%29%5D%0Apub%20struct%20Stride%3C%27a%2C%20I%3A%20Index%3Cuint%3E%20%2B%20%27a%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20items%3A%20%26%27a%20I%2C%0A%20%20%20%20len%3A%20uint%2C%0A%20%20%20%20current_idx%3A%20uint%2C%0A%20%20%20%20stride%3A%20uint%2C%0A%7D%0A%0Aimpl%3C%27a%2C%20I%3E%20Iterator%20for%20Stride%3C%27a%2C%20I%3E%20where%20I%3A%20Index%3Cuint%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20type%20Item%20%3D%20%26%27a%20%3CI%20as%20Index%3Cuint%3E%3E%3A%3AOutput%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%23%5Binline%5D%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20next%28%26mut%20self%29%20-%3E%20Option%3C%26%27a%20%3CI%20as%20Index%3Cuint%3E%3E%3A%3AOutput%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20%28self.current_idx%20%3E%3D%20self.len%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20None%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20idx%20%3D%20self.current_idx%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20self.current_idx%20%2B%3D%20self.stride%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Some%28self.items.index%28%26idx%29%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Afn%20main%28%29%20%7B%7D)