# error: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for autoref due to conflicting requirements [E0495]

Tags: iterator, rust, lifetime

First of all: I am fully aware of this post: [Cannot infer appropriate lifetime for autoref in Iterator impl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30868665/cannot-infer-appropriate-lifetime-for-autoderef-in-iterator-impl)
and that the problem is probably similar to mine.
However, I can't get it working with the knowledge of this thread.

The code:

```
use std::str::Chars;

use super::token::*;
use super::token_stream::TokenStream;

pub struct Lexer<'a> {
    input: Chars<'a>,
    buffer: String,
    cur_char: char
}

impl<'a> Lexer<'a> {
    pub fn new(iterator: Chars<'a>) -> Lexer {
        let mut lexer = Lexer {
            input: iterator,
            buffer: String::new(),
            cur_char: '\0' };
        lexer.consume_next();
        lexer
    }

    pub fn new_from_str(content : &str) -> Lexer {
        Lexer::new(content.chars())
    }

    fn consume_next(&mut self) -> char {
        let next = self.input.next();
        if let Some(c) = next {
            self.buffer.push(c);
            self.cur_char = c;
        }
        else {
            self.cur_char = '\0';
        }
        self.current_char()
    }

    fn clear_buffer(&mut self) {
        self.buffer.clear();
    }

    fn current_char(&self) -> char {
        self.cur_char
    }

    fn scan_line_comment(&self) -> Token { Token::EndOfFile }
    fn scan_multi_line_comment(&self) -> Token { Token::EndOfFile }


    fn scan_identifier(&self) -> Token { Token::EndOfFile }
    fn scan_char_literal(&self) -> Token { Token::EndOfFile }
    fn scan_string_literal(&self) -> Token { Token::EndOfFile }
    fn scan_number_literal(&self) -> Token { Token::EndOfFile }

    fn consume_and_return<'b>(&mut self, token: Token<'b>) -> Token<'b> {
        self.consume_next();
        token
    }
}

impl<'a> TokenStream for Lexer<'a> {
    fn next_token(&mut self) -> Token {
        match self.current_char() {
            /* Skip whitespace */
            ' '  |
            '\r' |
            '\n' |
            '\t' => {
                self.clear_buffer();
                self.consume_and_return(Token::Whitespace)
            }

            /* Opening delimiters */
            '(' => self.consume_and_return(Token::OpenDelim(DelimitToken::Paren)),
            '[' => self.consume_and_return(Token::OpenDelim(DelimitToken::Bracket)),
            '{' => self.consume_and_return(Token::OpenDelim(DelimitToken::Brace)),

            /* Opening delimiters */
            ')' => self.consume_and_return(Token::CloseDelim(DelimitToken::Paren)),
            ']' => self.consume_and_return(Token::CloseDelim(DelimitToken::Bracket)),
            '}' => self.consume_and_return(Token::CloseDelim(DelimitToken::Brace)),

            /* Special tokens which aren't the beginning
               of any other token */
            '?' => self.consume_and_return(Token::Question),
            ';' => self.consume_and_return(Token::SemiColon),
            ',' => self.consume_and_return(Token::Comma),

            /* Dot, DotDot and DotDotDot tokens */
            '.' => match self.consume_next() {
                '.' => match self.consume_next() {
                    '.' => self.consume_and_return(Token::DotDotDot),
                    _   => Token::DotDot
                },
                _ => Token::Dot
            },

            /* Tokens starting with '+' */
            '+' => match self.consume_next() {
                '=' => self.consume_and_return(Token::BinOpEq(BinOpToken::Plus)),
                _   => Token::BinOp(BinOpToken::Plus)
            },

            /* Tokens starting with '-' */
            '-' => match self.consume_next() {
                '=' => self.consume_and_return(Token::BinOpEq(BinOpToken::Minus)),
                '>' => self.consume_and_return(Token::Arrow),
                _   => Token::BinOp(BinOpToken::Minus)
            },

            /* Tokens starting with '*' */
            '*' => match self.consume_next() {
                '=' => self.consume_and_return(Token::BinOpEq(BinOpToken::Star)),
                _   => return Token::BinOp(BinOpToken::Star)
            },

            /* Tokens starting with '/' */
            '/' => match self.consume_next() {
                '=' => self.consume_and_return(Token::BinOpEq(BinOpToken::Slash)),
                '/' => self.scan_line_comment(),
                '*' => self.scan_multi_line_comment(),
                _ => Token::BinOp(BinOpToken::Slash)
            },

            /* Tokens starting with '%' */
            '%' => match self.consume_next() {
                '=' => self.consume_and_return(Token::BinOpEq(BinOpToken::Percent)),
                _   => Token::BinOp(BinOpToken::Percent)
            },

            /* Tokens starting with '^' */
            '^' => match self.consume_next() {
                '=' => self.consume_and_return(Token::BinOpEq(BinOpToken::Caret)),
                _   => return Token::BinOp(BinOpToken::Caret)
            },

            /* Tokens starting with '!' */
            '!' => match self.consume_next() {
                '=' => self.consume_and_return(Token::RelOp(RelOpToken::NotEq)),
                _   => Token::Exclamation
            },

            /* Tokens starting with '=' */
            '=' => match self.consume_next() {
                '=' => self.consume_and_return(Token::RelOp(RelOpToken::EqEq)),
                _   => Token::Eq
            },

            /* Tokens starting with '&' */
            '&' => match self.consume_next() {
                '&' => self.consume_and_return(Token::LogicalOp(LogicalOpToken::AndAnd)),
                '=' => self.consume_and_return(Token::BinOpEq(BinOpToken::And)),
                _   => Token::BinOp(BinOpToken::And)
            },

            /* Tokens starting with '|' */
            '|' => match self.consume_next() {
                '|' => self.consume_and_return(Token::LogicalOp(LogicalOpToken::OrOr)),
                '=' => self.consume_and_return(Token::BinOpEq(BinOpToken::Or)),
                _   => Token::BinOp(BinOpToken::Or)
            },

            /* Tokens starting with '<' */
            '<' => match self.consume_next() {
                '<' => match self.consume_next() {
                    '=' => self.consume_and_return(Token::BinOpEq(BinOpToken::Shl)),
                    _   => Token::BinOp(BinOpToken::Shl)
                },
                '=' => self.consume_and_return(Token::RelOp(RelOpToken::LessEq)),
                _   => Token::RelOp(RelOpToken::LessThan)
            },

            /* Tokens starting with '>' */
            '>' => match self.consume_next() {
                '>' => match self.consume_next() {
                    '=' => self.consume_and_return(Token::BinOpEq(BinOpToken::Shr)),
                    _   => Token::BinOp(BinOpToken::Shr)
                },
                '=' => self.consume_and_return(Token::RelOp(RelOpToken::GreaterEq)),
                _   => Token::RelOp(RelOpToken::GreaterThan)
            },

            /* Char and string literals */
            '\'' => self.scan_char_literal(),
            '\"' => self.scan_string_literal(),

            /* Integer- and float literals and identifiers */
            '0' ... '9' => self.scan_number_literal(),
            'a' ... 'z' |
            'A' ... 'Z' => self.scan_identifier(),

            /* When end of iterator has been reached */
            _ => Token::EndOfFile
        }
    }
}

impl<'a> Iterator for Lexer<'a> {
    type Item = Token<'a>;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        let token = self.next_token();
        match token {
            Token::EndOfFile => None,
            _                => Some(token)
        }
    }
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;
    use super::super::token::*;
    use super::super::token_stream::TokenStream;

    #[test]
    fn simple_tokens() {
        let solution = [
            Token::OpenDelim(DelimitToken::Paren),
            Token::CloseDelim(DelimitToken::Paren),

            Token::OpenDelim(DelimitToken::Bracket),
            Token::CloseDelim(DelimitToken::Bracket),

            Token::OpenDelim(DelimitToken::Brace),
            Token::CloseDelim(DelimitToken::Brace),

            Token::Question,
            Token::SemiColon,
            Token::Comma,

            Token::EndOfFile
        ];
        let mut lexer = Lexer::new_from_str("()[]{}?;,");
        for expected in &solution {
            assert_eq!(lexer.next_token(), *expected);
        }
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=b19c6d0a1174519cd2c4&version=stable)

And its dependent module 'Token':

```
#[derive(Clone, PartialEq, Eq, Hash, Debug, Copy)]
pub enum BinOpToken {
    Plus,    // +
    Minus,   // -
    Star,    // *
    Slash,   // /
    Percent, // %
    Caret,   // ^
    And,     // &
    Or,      // |
    Shl,     // <<
    Shr      // >>
}

#[derive(Clone, PartialEq, Eq, Hash, Debug, Copy)]
pub enum RelOpToken {
    EqEq,        // ==
    NotEq,       // !=
    LessThan,    // <
    LessEq,      // <=
    GreaterThan, // >
    GreaterEq    // >=
}

#[derive(Clone, PartialEq, Eq, Hash, Debug, Copy)]
pub enum LogicalOpToken {
    AndAnd, // &&
    OrOr    // ||
}

#[derive(Clone, PartialEq, Eq, Hash, Debug, Copy)]
pub enum DelimitToken {
    Paren,   // ( or )
    Bracket, // [ or ]
    Brace,   // { or }
}

#[derive(Clone, PartialEq, Eq, Hash, Debug, Copy)]
pub enum LiteralToken<'a> {
    Char(&'a str),    // e.g. 'a'
    Integer(&'a str), // e.g. 5, 42, 1337, 0
    Float(&'a str),   // e.g. 0.1, 5.0, 13.37, 0.0
    String(&'a str)   // e.g. "Hello, World!"
}

#[derive(Clone, PartialEq, Eq, Hash, Debug, Copy)]
pub enum Token<'a> {
    /* Logical operators, e.g. && or || */
    LogicalOp(LogicalOpToken),
    /* Binary operators compatible with assignment, e.g. +, - */
    BinOp(BinOpToken),
    /* Binary assignment operators, e.g. +=, -= */
    BinOpEq(BinOpToken),
    /* Relational operators, e.g. <, <=, >, >=, ==, != */
    RelOp(RelOpToken),

    /* An opening delimiter, e.g. { or ( or [ */
    OpenDelim(DelimitToken),

    /* A closing delimiter, e.g. } or ) or ] */
    CloseDelim(DelimitToken),

    /* Identifiers with their given name */
    Identifier(&'a str),
    /* Literal token, e.g. an integer, float or string literal */
    Literal(LiteralToken<'a>),

    /* Special tokens */
    Eq,          // =
    Colon,       // :
    SemiColon,   // ;
    ColonColon,  // ::
    Dot,         // .
    DotDot,      // ..
    DotDotDot,   // ...
    Comma,       // ,
    Exclamation, // !
    Question,    // ?
    Arrow,       // ->
    FatArrow,    // =>

    /* Junk tokens which the parser doesn't require in order to parse the program. */
    Whitespace,
    Comment,

    /* End of file (EOF) token indicating the end of stream for parsing */
    EndOfFile
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=b06bb97b5f97a8bd2d03&version=stable)

As well as the trait 'TokenStream':

```
pub use super::token::Token;

pub trait TokenStream {
    fn next_token(&mut self) -> Token;
}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
src/parser/lexer.rs:202:20: 202:32 error: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for autoref due to conflicting requirements [E0495]
src/parser/lexer.rs:202         let token = self.next_token();
                                                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I guess that it is a lifetime problem. My `next_token()` method returns a `Token` that has a lifetime independent of `Self`, however I am not sure if I did the annotation right.

I also tried to do some more annotation for the `next()` method in `Iterator` but it all failed ...

I get this error when I add a lifetime to the `&mut self` parameter of the `next()` method in the implementation of the `Iterator` trait:

```
src/parser/lexer.rs:201:2: 207:3 error: method `next` has an incompatible type for trait:
 expected bound lifetime parameter ,
    found concrete lifetime [E0053]
```

Comment: Your code is really, *really* large. Please take some time to produce an [MCVE](/help/mcve), emphasis on the **M**. Delete all methods that don't directly contribute to the error, replace function bodies with `unimplemented!`, remove parameters, struct members, enum variants. Combine all your code into *one* file. Ideally, produce an example that reproduces your code on the [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/). Taking the time to produce a clear example will help you understand where the problem occurs and makes it more likely that you will get a helpful answer.

Comment: Thank you for the reformatting! I have found a solution to my problem with the help of a friend and I am going to update the initial post with the solution. ;) However, sometime - as in this case - the errors are everywhere in the code, even in methods where you wouldn't expect them.

Comment: Done! ;) Hope, everything is okay with that answer.

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution to my problems and now everything compiles fine.

The problem was in fact a lifetime problem but not only within the `TokenStream` trait. I had lifetime issues in several places across the entire code.

Some notable places from the long code in the initial post:

lexer.rs: line 46 - 58

```
fn scan_line_comment<'b>(&self) -> Token<'b> { Token::EndOfFile }
fn scan_multi_line_comment<'b>(&self) -> Token<'b> { Token::EndOfFile }


fn scan_identifier<'b>(&self) -> Token<'b> { Token::EndOfFile }
fn scan_char_literal<'b>(&self) -> Token<'b> { Token::EndOfFile }
fn scan_string_literal<'b>(&self) -> Token<'b> { Token::EndOfFile }
fn scan_number_literal<'b>(&self) -> Token<'b> { Token::EndOfFile }

fn consume_and_return<'b>(&mut self, token: Token<'b>) -> Token<'b> {
    self.consume_next();
    token
}
```

I had to insert the lifetime `'b` to specify that the `Token` may outlive the `Lexer` instance.

The `TokenStream` required a new lifetime parameter so that it can specify that extended lifetime as well:

```
pub trait TokenStream<'a> {
    fn next_token(&mut self) -> Token<'a>;
}
```

The `TokenStream` implementation for `Lexer` had to be adjusted for this change:

```
impl<'a, 'b> TokenStream<'b> for Lexer<'a> {
    fn next_token(&mut self) -> Token<'b> {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

As well as the `Iterator` implementation for `Lexer`

```
impl<'a> Iterator for Lexer<'a> {
    type Item = Token<'a>;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        let token = self.next_token();
        match token {
            Token::EndOfFile => None,
            _                => Some(token)
        }
    }
}
```

That's it!