# Cannot infer an appropriate lifetime when building a struct with multiple references with the same lifetime

Tags: rust

I've seen multiple posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41270052/cannot-infer-an-appropriate-lifetime-for-autoref-due-to-conflicting-requirements) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35517514/error-cannot-infer-an-appropriate-lifetime-for-autoref-due-to-conflicting-requi) but I think this is no duplicate. I guess I haven't quite understood how to use lifetimes to outlive one another. Here is a MWE:

```
struct Point;

pub struct Line<'a> {
    pub start: &'a Point,
    pub end: &'a Point,
}

impl<'a> Line<'a> {
    pub fn new(start: &Point, end: &Point) -> Self {
        Line {
            start: start,
            end: end,
        }
    }
}

fn main() {}
```

I get the error message

```
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for lifetime parameter `'a` due to conflicting requirements
  --> src/main.rs:10:9
   |
10 |         Line {
   |         ^^^^
   |
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the anonymous lifetime #2 defined on the body at 9:51...
  --> src/main.rs:9:52
   |
9  |       pub fn new(start: &Point, end: &Point) -> Self {
   |  ____________________________________________________^
10 | |         Line {
11 | |             start: start,
12 | |             end: end,
13 | |         }
14 | |     }
   | |_____^
note: ...so that reference does not outlive borrowed content
  --> src/main.rs:12:18
   |
12 |             end: end,
   |                  ^^^
note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the lifetime 'a as defined on the body at 9:51...
  --> src/main.rs:9:52
   |
9  |       pub fn new(start: &Point, end: &Point) -> Self {
   |  ____________________________________________________^
10 | |         Line {
11 | |             start: start,
12 | |             end: end,
13 | |         }
14 | |     }
   | |_____^
note: ...so that expression is assignable (expected Line<'a>, found Line<'_>)
  --> src/main.rs:10:9
   |
10 | /         Line {
11 | |             start: start,
12 | |             end: end,
13 | |         }
   | |_________^
```

and I am completely lost about how to interpret it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to explicitly specify the lifetime of both parameters so that they are the same:

```
impl<'a> Line<'a> {
    pub fn new(start: &'a Point, end: &'a Point) -> Self {
        Line {
            start: start,
            end: end,
        }
    }
}
```

Otherwise the compiler cannot decide which input lifetime to choose for the output. I recommend the relevant [Rust Book section on lifetime elision](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/first-edition/lifetimes.html#lifetime-elision), especially the following 3 rules:

> - Each elided lifetime in a function’s arguments becomes a distinct lifetime 
>     parameter.
> - If there is exactly one input lifetime, elided or not, that lifetime
>     is assigned to all elided lifetimes in the return values of that
>     function.
> - If there are multiple input lifetimes, but one of them is &self or
>     &mut self, the lifetime of self is assigned to all elided output
>     lifetimes.
>
> Otherwise, it is an error to elide an output lifetime.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. I guess I have to read once more over lifetimes and borrowing.